# How can I access an API without running into Allow Access Control Origin issues?

Tags: javascript, cors, http-headers, cuckoo

I've noticed that this seems to be a commonly asked question, but none of the responses I've seen have helped so far.
I'm trying to access an API (Cuckoo Sandbox, set up on a VM) from my JavaScript+TypeScript application using an Axios call. This is what the code to call the API looks like.

```
      axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.220:1337/tasks/view',
    headers: {          
     'Authorization': 'Bearer WoRKpl5',
    //  'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  }).then(resp =>{
    console.log("Hi")
  }).catch(err => { // then print response status
    console.log(err)
  });
```

The response is as shown below:
[image: Image of response]

So far, I've tried editing the api_py file for cuckoo to include headers in the do_post function, modifying the headers in the axios call (commented out), running Chrome browser after disabling web security, trying to disable CORS (unsure if successful) and using a Proxy (CORS-anywhere) hosted on Heroku to add headers, among other things, without much success. Cuckoo Sandbox constantly receives only Options requests. Here is a screenshot of the current headers in the Cuckoo file:

[image: Image of headers]

I found it interesting to note that through the regular command line interface and the curl command, the API was working and we could successfully access it.
Any further insight on how to successfully hit the API from the application for both GET and POST requests would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' or making the request to http://localhost:1337/tasks/view?

Comment: Yes, we have tried making the request to a few different urls, including localhost:1337/tasks/view 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*' was also tried. I just tried the following with no success either, if this is what you meant: 

         headers: {          
         'Authorization': 'Bearer WoRKpl5',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'

Comment: No, I mean on your server. You have to set the server response header to { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:3000'} or replace the value for a * if you want everyone to be allowed